# How to create a half diamond shape with nested loops?

Tags: java, nested-loops

Currently, my program is outputting this:

```
         p
        r r
       o o o
      g g g g
     r r r r r
    a a a a a a
   m m m m m m m
```

I wanted it to output this:

```
         pp
        r  r
       o    o
      g      g
     r        r
    a          a
   m            m
```

I'm not sure hot to go about doing this. I've worked on it for quite awhile, and can't seem how to first make it have a double "p" at the beginning, and then I'm not sure how to create spaces between those letters like the true output looks like. Please help.

Here is my current code:

```
String output = "";
    String str = "program";
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i=0 ; i<length; i++)
    {
        for (int k=length-1; k>i; k--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Break down each line. The first line is "9 spaces, letter, 0 spaces, letter". The second is "8 spaces, letter, 2 spaces, letter". The third is "7 spaces, letter, 4 spaces, letter." Now find the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The two problems you have is that in the inner loop:

```
for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
}
```

You aren't printing enough spaces (It should be `j < i * 2`), and you don't want to print `str.charAt(i)` on every iteration of the loop. Only before and after:

```
String output = "";
String str = "program";
int length = str.length();
for (int i=0 ; i<length; i++)
{
    for (int k=length-1; k>i; k--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    for (int j=0; j< i*2; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");        
    }
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    System.out.println();
}
```

***Output:***

```
      pp
     r  r
    o    o
   g      g
  r        r
 a          a
m            m
```

Comment: Thank you! it all works with one exception: how can I make there no space between the first two "p" letters? so it's "pp"?

Comment: @CT3 Updated. Just do `<` instead of `<=`